# Configure Mautic to send 6 emails per minute

Tags: email, cron, mautic

I have around 50,000 email addresses and I wish to send them all a common email.
I have an upper limit of 360 emails per hour. (6 emails per minute)

These are the settings I have set-up in my Mautic server

Under Mail Send Settings

- How should email be handled? ---> Queue
- Path to the email queue directory ---> %kernel.root_dir%/spool
- Message limit for queue processing ---> 10
- Time limit for queue processing ---> 60
- Recovery timeout for resending failed messages ---> 900
- Clear timeout for deleted failed messages ---> 1800

These are my Cron Jobs

15 minutes

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/myDir/email.mydomain.com/app/console mautic:webhooks:process > /dev/null 2>&1
```

10 Minutes

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/myDir/email.mydomain.com/app/console mautic:leadlists:update > /dev/null 2>&1

/usr/local/bin/php /home/myDir/email.mydomain.com/app/console mautic:campaigns:update > /dev/null 2>&1

/usr/local/bin/php /home/myDir/email.mydomain.com/app/console mautic:campaigns:trigger > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Every Minute

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/myDir/email.mydomain.com/app/console mautic:email:process > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Once Per Day

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/myDir/email.mydomain.com/app/console mautic:fetch:email > /dev/null 2>&1
/usr/local/bin/php /home/myDir/email.mydomain.com/app/console mautic:iplookup:download > /dev/null 2>&1
```

I ended up sending only 400 emails(Upper limit the server allows) and all the other emails getting discarded by my server.

What should be the correct settings?
Do I need to add any other cronjob?

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted to send exactly 6 emails a minute, you could use:

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/myDir/email.mydomain.com/app/console mautic:email:process --message-limit=6 > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Or adjust the cron interval / message limit in any other way to stay below your quota.

Answer (score 1):

Important: In order to do that you need to change your broadcast and rebuild cron as well. Let me explain the reason. When broadcast cron runs generate all emails, so the email date is generated at that time, when we put a limit to send, these emails can be stuck in Mautic for hours, thereby Gmail, Hotmail, and other emails providers don't like to receive an email with an old date and that can harm your deliverability. One alternative is to set the broadcast and campaign rebuild crons the same limit, for example, 6 emails per batch and 1 minute for each interval. I would suggest a bigger interval, a one-minute interval for big contacts lists will overlap the processes and Mautic may lose performance.